# I'm falling in overtesting feature

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript

I'm fresh in the world of unit testing / integration testing. And I have read that, to write good unit tests for methods and classes, you must put yourself in the context that you don't know much about the method implementation, and focus on the method interface and logic

> for example methode `add` take 2 params and return the sum of its

So here is a real life example of a method that I had to write tests for:

```
  matchLeague(summoner: SummonerTeammate): boolean {

    // check that maximum difference between summoners tiers is one tier
    if(Math.abs(this.summoner_league_info.tier - summoner.summoner_league_info.tier) > 1) {
      return false
    }

    return true;
  }
```

And here are the tests that I have written:

```
describe('match league algorithme', () => {

    function matchingHelper(tier1, tier2, excp) {
      let sum1: SummonerTeammate = new SummonerTeammate({
        summoner_league_info: {
          tier: tier1,
        }
      })

      let sum2: SummonerTeammate = new SummonerTeammate({
        summoner_league_info: {
          tier: tier2,
        }
      });

      expect(sum1.matchLeague(sum2)).toBe(excp)
    }

    test('should return true if players are in same tier', () => {
      matchingHelper(1, 1, true)
    })

    test('should return true if player1 is 1 tier below player 2 tier', () => {
      matchingHelper(1, 2, true)
    })

    test('should return true if player1 is 1 tier above player 2 tier', () => {
      matchingHelper(2, 1, true)
    })

    test('should return false if player 1 is more than 1 tier above player 2', () => {
      matchingHelper(3, 1, false)
      matchingHelper(7, 1, false)
      matchingHelper(6, 1, false)
    })

    test('should return false if player 1 is more than 1 tier below player 2', () => {
      matchingHelper(4, 6, false)
      matchingHelper(2, 6, false)
      matchingHelper(1, 6, false)
    })
  })
```

So, what I want to know, is that if my test suite is good for this methode, or I'm testing too much or too little case.

Comment: To me, this seems pretty good. You could add more, but it depends. Remember, your tests are the bounds of your expectations, so this seems fine. You could try to throw invalid input at the function, like negative numbers, fractions, `Number.MAX_VALUE`, strings, other data types, etc. However, if you would never really expect such values to be passed in, the tests won't really be worth it. On the other hand, if you *could* have invalid input somehow and no tests for it, you are left open. It's always a balancing act.

Comment: Did you estimate what your test coverage would be with this?